# NO response when launching Anaconda spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

It's my first time to install anaconda in my computer, but when I try to open spyder with anaconda start menu, **I got no response**

```
Spyder version : 3.3.1

Anaconda Navigator version:1.9.2
```

I've tried so many steps, but it still didn't worked

If I'm missing any detail, please let me know

[image]

Comment: try running command `spyder` in terminal or cmd

Comment: it worked!!! thanks!!!!